# Gradle coding convention: Setting conventions for properties in Gradle tasks

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose I am creating a task, with a property that has a convention:

```kotlin
abstract class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Internal
    abstract val myProperty: Property<String>
    
    init {
        myProperty.convention("foobar")
    }
}
```

The IDE flags the use of `myProperty` in the init block because `myProperty` is non-final. Is this acceptable for Gradle purposes, and if not, what is the preferred way to avoid the compiler warning? (Can it be done without explicitly injecting an `ObjectFactory`?)

Comment: Related Gradle issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/24773

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it. While the compiler warning might be useful in other cases, it is mere noise here as it is actually wanted behavior in this case. I'd suggest to `@Suppress` it for Gradle decorated objects.